# Ajax not getting proper URL from server path in jsp using struts 2

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, jsp, struts2

Am storing some JSON files dynamically in server path and retrieve the JSON data using struts 2 framework. When requesting for AJAX call to retrieve the JSON I am getting URL path as `www.mydomain.com:8080/mydomain.com/myserver/myjsonpath/jsonfile.json` instead of getting `http://www.mydomain.com/myserver/myjsonpath/jsonfile.json`. I also want to mention that due this i cannot enter into success field of AJAX.It always enters into error field. I came to know this URL append with the help of Firebug.

```
//My AJAX request

String img_path="www.mydomain.com/myserver/";
String json_url=img_path+"/myjsonpath";

$(document).ready(function(){
   alert("<%=json_url%>/jsonfile.json"); // here am getting correct URL path from server
   $.ajax({
           type: "get",
           url:"<%=json_url%>/jsonfile.json",
           dataType: "json",
           success:function(data){
                   alert(data);    // not entering here
           error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                   alert(xhr.status); // enters here
 }});
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all using scriplets is not at all a good idea.

To your avail there's `s:url` tag & here's how to use it.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   alert("<s:url value="myserver/myjsonpath"/>/jsonfile.json");
//...
});
```